Why can we choose lifts $\tilde{\alpha}$ and $\tilde{\beta}$ of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ that have the same endpoints in $\partial\mathbb{H}^2$?
My question refers to the proof given in http://euclid.nmu.edu/~joshthom/Teaching/MA589/farbmarg.pdf, page 34. Proposition 1.10 states the following:

Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be two essential simple closed curves in a surface $S$. Then $\alpha$ is isotopic to $\beta$ if and only if
$\alpha$ is homotopic to $\beta$.

I have two questions regarding the proof given in PMCG. Firstly, why is it enough to look at the curves corresponding to hyperbolic isometries of $\mathbb{H}^2$, it is the only case given for a hyperbolic surface. Does it follow from the fact that a curve corresponding to a parabolic isometry can be freely homotoped to any given neighborhood of a puncture and thus is not essential? The second question regards the very beggining of the case $\chi(S)<0$:
Assume $\chi(S)<0$. Choose lifts $\tilde{\alpha}$ and $\tilde{\beta}$ of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ that have the same endpoints in $\partial\mathbb{H}^2$.
Why can we choose lifts such that endpoints are the same? Rest of the proof is clear for me.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2867788/lifts-of-2-curves-in-the-same-homotopy-class?rq=1

@MoisheKohan thank you for your answer. I know that freely homotopic loops are conjugate in fundamental group and thus respective isommetries are conjugate in a deck transformation group provided we work with an universal cover. But I don't see how we conclude that we can choose lifts with such endpoints.
